# Install ADT for eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am tring to install ADT for eclipse but get a long error message starting with 'Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.'  I did notice it has the following in the error message:

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.6.0.v20100505 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0.v20100505)
    Core Runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.8.0.v20120912-155025)

does that mean I have to uninstall java 3.6 ? (I thought I had uninstalled 3.6 when I installed 3.8)  if so how do I do it.  The eclipse version i'm trying to install on is kepler.

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that you have version 3.6.0.v20100505 of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin installed in your Eclipse, but ADT requires a minimum of version 3.8.0.

Version 3.6.0 of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` is part of Eclipse Helios (3.6) which is very old. Version 3.8.0 was first released in Eclipse Juno (3.8/4.2).

So you need to move to a newer version of Eclipse - Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is the current release.